# Functionally add a list of Integers

Tags: java, recursion, functional-programming

As the title says, I am trying to add a list of integers using the functional programming paradigm. So, no mutation at all.  This is a homework assignment, and the method definition has been set by my professor, and that is part of why I am stuck, this is what I have so far:

```
public static Integer sum(final List<Integer> values) {
     if(values.size() == 1) {
             return values.get(0);
     }
     else {
             List<Integer> tempList;
             tempList = values.subList(0, values.size() - 1);
             return sum(tempList);
     }
 }
```

I can only return a List, and cannot modify it in any way after its creation, and have no access to a constructor due to the generic List being used.
I may be going about this in the wrong way, I'm trying to think of a way to add the last two values in the list and place that sum in the last spot of a new list that is one index shorter.
If you see a better way to do this or can push me toward the answer I would appreciate it, its homework so not looking for a completed code block.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to use recursion? If not, see the reply by Bohemian. It is the most logical solution.

Comment: Note that your code will cause an exception for empty lists. Usually the sum function is defined with the empty list as the base case - not lists of size 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `else` branch should include the first number in the list. Besides, you should fix the second argument in your call to `List.sublist`. The two parameters of `List.sublist(fromIndex, toIndex)` specify a sublist. `fromIndex` in inclusive but `toIndex` is exclusive.

Comment: Didn't he say he was not looking for a completed code block? :)

Comment: (+1) Nice hints. My only comments is that *"the first number"* isn't quite consistent with the code he already has (should be the *last*).

Comment: repro, I got a look at your code for about 2 seconds before you edited it heh. Two questions: what does sum(list) do and can you be a little more specific on what is wrong with my sublist?
Thanks.

Comment: @JakeSellers If you really want to look at his code, the full revision history of his answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13612704/revisions

Comment: Ah, thanks, but I would still like to understand what he was doing instead of just copy-pasting it.

Comment: I explained the difference between the two parameters of `List.subList` in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edited:

Oh I see - you want a *recursive* solution. Try this one-liner, which technically doesn't even use an `if` statement:

```
public static Integer sum(final List<Integer> values) {
     return values.isEmpty() ? 0 : values.get(0) + sum(subList(1, values.size());
}
```

this would probably get you a score of 9/10. For full marks, you would need to add null safety:

```
public static Integer sum(final List<Integer> values) {
     return values == null || values.isEmpty() ? 0 : values.get(0) + sum(subList(1, values.size());
}
```

---

Full disclosure, previously I had this:

You have too much code!

```
public static Integer sum(final List<Integer> values) {
     int total = 0;
     for (int i : values) {
         total += i;
     }
     return total;
}
```

fyi, auto-boxing converts smoothly between `int` and `Integer`

Comment: I didn't vote either way, but he did say *using the functional programming paradigm*. I don't think a `for` loop counts. :)

Comment: You're using a mutable variable in your code (`total`). That is not what was asked for.

Comment: Yes, all assignment statements and loops are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Your original answer is very close.

Hint: You're getting a sublist that consists of the original list minus the last element, but you just throw that last element away - you never use it's value.  Perhaps it should be somewhere included in the sum of the sublist? (answer = yes)

Also, I'd probably throw in at the top of the method:

```
if (values == null || values.isEmpty())
{
  return null;
}
```

Comment: The sum of an empty list of integers is traditionally known as `0`, rather than `null`. Nulls cause enough problems without returning them for perfectly well-specified input values.

Comment: I might be convinced that an empty list would return 0 (although not yet convinced), I certainly wouldn't return 0 for a null list.  Either returning null or throwing an IAE would likely be better.

Comment: The empty sum **is** 0. If you think of multiplication as repeated addition, `3 * x` is `x + x + x`. So adding together 0 xs should correspond to `0 * x`. Similarly the empty product is 1 (`x^0 = 1`), the empty disjunction (`||` a list of booleans) is `false`, and the empty conjunction (`&&` a list of booleans) is `true`. Something as generic as a `sum` operation really ought to be consistent with the standard mathematical definition of `sum`. I agree that `null` is not an empty list, but rather an ill-defined one, and doesn't have a well-defined sum.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a list in Haskell, as a way to see the obvious solutions. sum is a foldr with addition:

```
 sum xs = foldr (+) 0 xs
```

Inline foldr

```
 sum xs = go (+) 0 xs
     where
         go _ z []     =  z
         go f z (x:xs) =  f x (go f z xs)
```

Specialize to (+)

```
 sum xs = go xs
     where
         go []     = 0
         go (x:xs) = x + (go xs)
```

Inline go to get our final answer:

```
 sum []     = 0
 sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

so that's the basic recursive solution. It works just as well for empty lists or lists with one or more elements. You can translate it directly to Java (my Java is super rusty):

```
 public static Integer sum(final List<Integer> xs) {
     if(xs.size() == 0) {
         return 0;
     } else {
         return xs.get(0) + sum(subList(1, xs.size());
     }
 }
```